# how to check if gpg public key is already added to public keyring in gpg

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I am developing the mvc4 .net  web application where i am using GPG encryption to file encryption

users will share public key with application.

Application will encrypt the file using user public key and application private key.

user public key will be imported to application public key ring.

now i want to check if particular public key is already exist in public key ring.

Please suggest the command for the same .

Thanks ,
amol

Answer (score 2):

Call `gpg --list-keys 0xdeadbeef`, which will return all matching keys for the given key id. You should use the `0x` notation, so that GnuPG doesn't start a string match on the UIDs instead. If you have a longer key id or even the whole fingerprint, you can also use this.

Now given two cases:

- **Key is available:** Result on STDOUT containing information on the key.
- **Key is not available:** Error message on STDERR with the information that no public key was found